# DKIM/SPF problem causing lots of DMARC reports

Tags: email, dns, email-spoofing, spf, dkim

I get messages from "noreply-dmarc-support@google.com" with a DMARC report as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<feedback>
  <report_metadata>
    <org_name>google.com</org_name>
    <email>noreply-dmarc-support@google.com</email>
    <extra_contact_info>https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580</extra_contact_info>
    <report_id>---omited---</report_id>
    <date_range>
      <begin>1472169600</begin>
      <end>1472255999</end>
    </date_range>
  </report_metadata>
  <policy_published>
    <domain>mydomain.com</domain>
    <adkim>r</adkim>
    <aspf>r</aspf>
    <p>reject</p>
    <sp>reject</sp>
    <pct>100</pct>
  </policy_published>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>74.201.84.163</source_ip>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>mydomain.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>mydomain.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>mydomain.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
</feedback>
```

My spf records are:

```
v=spf1 mx include:zoho.com -all
```

(zoho is my mail provider, however they are not technically enough to solve this problem...).
If I do an IP lookup of

```
Source: whois.arin.netIP
Address: 74.201.84.163 (United States)
Name: INAP-SJE-ZOHO-35799
Handle: NET-74-201-84-0-1
Registration Date: 11/30/09
Range: 74.201.84.0-74.201.84.255
Customer: ZOHO Corporation
Customer Handle: C02367412
Address: 5200 Franklin Dr, Suite 115
City: PleasantonState/Province: 
CAPostal Code: 94588
Country: UNITED STATES
```

And the domain sender163-mail.zoho.com points to the above IP.
Which all appear to be in range of my SPF record. I have no idea why I receive these messages because everything seems to be in place...

Comment: Could it simply be because you're asking to include `zoho.com`'s SPF record which doesn't exist?

Comment: @JuliePelletier: there is an SPF record for zoho.com, see `dig txt zoho.com`: `v=spf1 include:spf2.zoho.com include:spf.zoho.com  ~all`. And for `spf.zoho.com` and `spf2.zoho.com` records exist too.

Comment: Oh right.  It's the DMARC policy which is set to reject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an error report but an aggregate report you probably requested by providing the appropriate DMARC policy (i.e. setting the `rua` field). The report shows that both DKIM and SPF check pass for this IP address. For more information about how to read this report and how to request it (or stop it) see [How to Read Your First DMARC Reports](https://blog.returnpath.com/how-to-read-your-first-dmarc-reports-part-1/).

Comment: So the report also describes messages without DKIM or SPF problems? I thought only the incorrect ones.

Comment: @Criticaljoe: the information about this topic are often confusing since in the examples you usually have something fail. But the aggregate report actually includes everything. See also the picture in https://dmarc.org/overview/ where you see that pass, quarantine and reject are all added to the aggregate report.